# Cant fin definition of XMapWindow() in Xlib headers

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

So i have this simple code that draws a small window using X11

```cpp
int main(int, char*[])
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window window = XCreateSimpleWindow(
        display, XDefaultRootWindow(display),
        100, 100, 200, 200, 4, 0, 0);
    XEvent event;

    XMapWindow(display, window);
    XSelectInput(display, window, KeyPressMask | ButtonPressMask | ExposureMask);

    while (True) {
      XNextEvent(display, &event);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine, the window its drawed without problems.

The thing is i really want to understand how X11 works so im reading the source code of the headers but im unable to find the difinition for XMapWindow() i need help.

This was the only similutede i could find in the Xlib.h header file.

```cpp
extern int XMapWindow(
    Display*        /* display */,
    Window      /* w */
);
```

Comment: Header files shouldn't generally contain function definitions, only declarations. If you want the definition you need to get the source for the actual *library*. But note that the X11 source is anything but trivial, reading it won't really tell you how X11 works. You're better of reading books.

Comment: Also remember that X11 is actually a networked client-server system. Most of the functionality won't be in xlib at all, those functions just wraps the communication between the client and the server.

Comment: Probably this could help a bit: https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XMapWindow  https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XMapWindow.html

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so theres a way to fin the source code for those functions? im really interested in knowing how X11 operates at low level

Comment: If you can get copies of the old X11 books from O'Reilly I really recommend them in favor or reading the mess that any X11 implementation will be. Bit with that said, figure out which distribution package contains the binary libraries, and you can find out what source packages they were built from. Then you can easily get those packages for the source to read. Last I checked (many many years ago) it was several hundreds of thousands of lines of code. Not all will be relevant but it's still a lot to wade through.

Comment: If you are looking for a X11 server implementation you could take a look at the XFree86 open source implementation. But you can't learn how YOUR X-server will perform the request if it's not XFree86.

Comment: And note that more and more distributions are turning away from pure X11 implementation, in favor of e.g. Wayland. Such systems will only have have an X11 compatibility layer on top of Wayland. If it makes thing simpler or more complicated I don't really know.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the note, this all started beceause i got curious in how GUI programming at low level works, without using toolkits like GTK or QT, so i found out that X11 works at low level on top of the Kernel and thats why i wanted to understand how the server works hehehe. btw sorry if my english is bad

Answer (score 1):

You can find the implementation of `XMapWindow()` in the [libX11 sources](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11), specifically in [src/MapWindow.c:XMapWindow()](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/master/src/MapWindow.c).

It boils down to some locking, and a `_XGetRequest(dpy, X_MapWindow, SIZEOF(xResourceReq))` call.  That is defined in [src/XlibInt.c:_XGetRequest()](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/master/src/XlibInt.c), and as you can guess by the name, adds the X_MapWindow request to the request queue sent to the X server.

How the X server (which manages the actual display) acts on that, is up to that X server implementation.